# jQuery animate() showing error of $(...).animate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Alive Time</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:100px"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size:100px"></i>

  </body>

</html>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.fa-cog{
    margin: 10% 50%;
    color: red;
    /*-moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;*/
}




.down {
       -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".fa-cog").on('mouseenter',function(){
 $(this).animate({rotate:180},{
  step:function(now,fx){

    /*$(this).css({' -moz-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',
    'transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)'});*/

    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
  },duration:'slow'},'linear'); 
});
});
```

Guys I am trying to use specifically animate() method of jquery to rotate a cog. I know I can make a class use some transition,transform and then add or remove that class. But I want to use animate() up here. Couple of docs on stackoverflow said that we don’t actually have to use a real CSS property, like text-index or border-spacing, but instead you can specify a fake CSS property, like rotation or my-awesome-property or else. It might be a good idea to use something that does not risk becoming an actual CSS property in the future. I tried every thing couldnt find the mistake in my code. Ignore the code which I have commented out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

You can't use the slim version of the jQuery, in your case, as this version is **without** animations. Just replace it with this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are using slim version of jQuery which does not include animation library. Please use the full version of jQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```